# Ruby on Rails - No route for delete issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am using rails to develop a clone of Twitter. I have the function that adds a 'Follow' record to the database correctly, but I am getting an error when I try to 'Unfollow' that User.

Helper method

```
def find_user(user)
    user = User.where(email: user.email).first
    #id = user.id
    return user.id
end


def destroy
    #@follow = Follow.where('user_id = ? AND follows = ?',current_user.id,params[:user_id]).first
    @follow = params[:user]
    p "follow to delete "+@follow
    #@follow.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

View

```
<% @users.try(:each) do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.first_name + " " + user.last_name %></td>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td>
            <% if follow = user.follows.find_by(follows: user.id) %>
                <%= link_to 'Unfollow', follow_path(:user => find_user(user)), method: :delete %>

            <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'Follow', follows_path({user_id: user.id}), method: 'post',class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Error

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"follows", :user=>1}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

I am using the resources :follows in the routes

I am sure I am not catching something but it seems that everything is right.

Comment: What's in your routes file? What route are you currently requesting? If the view you pasted is show.html.erb, then you're probably doing something wrong with params or something in the show action.

Answer (score 0):

```
follow_path(:user => find_user(user))
```

Looks janky given the error. Have you tried:

```
follow_path(:id => find_user(user))
```

Given the lack of info difficult to debug, though.